# Conditional comprehension in Julia

Tags: python, if-statement, filter, list-comprehension, julia

In Python, there is the option to provide a condition for whether or not to include a specific item in a comprehension.

```
[x**2 for x in range(10) if x > 5]
# [36, 49, 64, 81]
```

It is possible to conditionally use function, but I have not yet found a way to entirely exclude values, other than `filter!`ing them outside of the comprehension.

```
l = collect(0:9)
filter!(x -> x > 5, l)
l = [x^2 for x in l]  # alternatively, map!(x -> x^2, l)
# [36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Is this possible in Julia?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is possible in the latest Julia.

```
julia> [x^2 for x in 0:9 if x > 5]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 36
 49
 64
 81
```

Otherwise, yes, if you're using pre 0.5 you're stuck with:

```
[x^2 for x in filter((x) -> x > 5, 0:9)]
```

Comment: @2Cubed 0.4.6 is the 'stable' release. But the 'nightly' releases are available for download already from the website. (it's currently at 0.6+!)

Comment: Indeed. IMO 0.5 has a good stability/feature balance at the moment so I would go for that if I were you @2Cubed

Comment: @AlexanderMorley It looks that there are release candidates for 0.5 already - there should be a full release very soon!

Comment: @2Cubed Yeap, currently, v0.5 is the default version.

Comment: Just want to note that this confuses Pycharm for example. Has anyone successfully used this syntax in Pycharm? I mostly use Python with a bit of Julia (same tool). Is there a more Julia compatible IDE to be using?

Comment: @DeanKayton the IDE of choice as per the [JuliaPro](https://juliacomputing.com/products/juliapro.html) offering of julia seems to be [Juno](http://junolab.org/). Have you tried that?

Comment: No, although it is ringin a bell. Will give it a go, thanks.